# Make a website add a bookmark to your android-homescreen

Tags: android, bookmarks, homescreen

Is it possible to add a link to a simple html-site that puts a bookmark of that same site on the android-homescreen?

This should take these steps away for the user: "Add to bookmarks" + "Put bookmark on home screen"

Comment: Do you mean programmatically?

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this? I would like the answer to this, as well as for BlackBerry!

Comment: No, it is not possible. At least not for android/ios.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i don't believe this can be done programmatically but checkout out https://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/ and http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen/ in the meantime

Comment: Those are iOS solutions, not Android.